# Access mongdb using compass

Tags: mongodb, azure, haproxy

I'm trying new GUI of MongoDB called Compass.

However, my MongoDB server is on the Azure virtual machine which has private IP only.

All Azure servers in our subnet are accessible via one server called monitoring Server which has public IP and one haproxy is installed on it.

So how do I access MongoDB from my desktop(centos) using Compass?

Comment: This type of question is better suited for ServerFault, as it's not programming-related, rather infrastructure-related. That said: Unless you open up your local IP address for access, or use some type of vpn, you simply won't have access since your network is locked down. You'd need to install Compass on a machine that has access (maybe a VM in your vnet?). Maybe configure haproxy to allow Compass to reach your MongoDB VM?

Comment: If the answer is helpful or for more help, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

For Azure VM, you just can connect it through the public IP or Azure Load Balancer with the NAT rules. Also for MongoDB.

If you can make your monitoring as a router and can redirect your connection to the VM of MongoDB so that you can connect the MongoDB. If not, you cannot connect your MongoDB.

You can take a look at the [Azure Load Balancer with NAT rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/tutorial-load-balancer-port-forwarding-portal) if you don't want to connect directly to the VM which MongoDB on it.